# Calculate AVG base on dayweek SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I'm working whit a MariaDB database.
I need to know, for every day in a certain time the avg of a count. 
I'd tried somethink like this.

```
SELECT AVG(dayShipments), weekdays
    FROM (SELECT COUNT(idShipment) as "dayShipments", WEEKDAY(dateShipments) as "weekdays"
            FROM weekdays
            WHERE dateShipments BETWEEN '2021-05-01'AND '2021-05-21'
            GROUP BY dateShipments) as t1
     GROUP BY weekdays
```

My boss told me that this query ignore the day where I don't have any Shipment.
How can i inlude that?
Sorry for my bad English and thanks for helping me

Comment: Your statement and your query do different things.  And, what do you want done with days with no shipments?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to summary by day-of-the-week (which is what your query appears to be doing.  And you want to treat days with no shipments as `0`, then use `SUM()` and division:

```
SELECT WEEKDAY(dateShipments) as weekday,
       COUNT(*) / 3 as dayShipments as avg_per_day
FROM weekdays
WHERE dateShipments BETWEEN '2021-05-01'AND '2021-05-21'
GROUP BY weekday;
```

The `3` is because the query spans three weeks.

Comment: This script have the same problem pf mine. The result set should be sometink like {"Monday": 1.5, "Tuesday": 4.1, ... }. But whit your script (and mine too) if a monday I don't have any Shipment (so the count is '0') the AVG() function don't count the '0' value.

Comment: @FrancescoDellaMaggiora . . . If a weekday is missing, then it is counted as missing.  If there is no rows at all for a particular weekday, then it will not be in the result set.

Answer (score 0):

First of all don't worry about your english. It's good enough.

Secondly, your boss is right. If you have no records in "weekdays" table for specific day, the mentioned day will never show up with this query.
For solving problem I think you need to have a temporary table for day of week and left join with your **t1**  table.